# Azure Emulator really slow

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-emulator

a week now my solution which has a Azure Web Role is very slow, showing a message telling that it's take longer than expected and some times starting using 127.0.0.2:82, before this last week always had been works normally and this thing of starting using other ip and port never came up.

And while the emulator is starting my browser become very slow, not loading pages until the emulator load it up.

There is a way to improve this or another to not use Azure Emulator?

Answer (score 0):

When you exits the emulator without shutting down the web role, it won't discard the deployment. 
The emulator will create a new site in IIS and increment ip when starting the compute emulation again, since the last deployment still exists. If you shutdown your compute emulator correctly it won't happen again.

Another tip is using IIS Express, it is a little faster then using full IIS.

Comment: I always used IIS Express, but since one week until now became slower.